# How do I rewrite redirects to plain routes using react router?

Tags: javascript, react-router, jsx

Using `react 15.1.0` and `react-router 2.5.2`, I wish to rewrite the following JSX syntax:

```
<Router routes={routes} history={hashHistory}>
  <Redirect from="/" to="/users" />
  <Route path="/" component={Navigation}>
    <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage}/>
    <Route path="/endpoints" component={EndpointsPage}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Into plain routes, like this:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: Navigation,
  childRoutes: [
    {path: '/users', component: UsersPage},
    {path: '/endpoints', component: EndpointsPage}
  ],
  onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/users')
};

React.render(<Router routes={routes} history={hashHistory}/>, element);
```

However the result of the latter is always:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The `onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/users')` is apparently not sufficient to replace the `<Redirect from="/" to="/users" />`. How can I rewrite the redirect successfully? Is there a better way to make navigation to `/` always end up at `/users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a thing called `IndexRedirect` which I was unaware of. Using index redirect, the correct way to do this in plain routes is:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: Navigation,
  indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/users')},
  childRoutes: [
    {path: '/users', component: UsersPage},
    {path: '/endpoints', component: EndpointsPage}
  ]
};

React.render(<Router routes={routes} history={hashHistory}/>, element);
```